# Does `git commit` commit changes that were not added

Tags: git

I'm trying to learn git using the 'Pro Git' book by Scott Chacon. When explaining how to Stage modified files (page 18), i understand with `git add` the files are scheduled for commit and then commited with `git commit`. It mentions that a commit is done, only the changes that were added will be actually be commited, and if i change a file again, i'd have to add it againg before commit so that all changes are comitted. The text says:

> It turns out that Git stages a file exactly as it is when you run the `git add`
>   command.If you commit now, the version of the file as it was when you last ran the `git add`
>   command is how it will go into the commit, not the version of the file as it looks in your working directory when you run `git commit`. If you modify a file after you run `git add`
>   , you have to run `git add` again to stage the latest version of the file.

However, i'm seeing a different behaviour when trying it myself:

```
$ git status              #start clean
#On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

$ echo "hello" >> README.TXT 
git-question> git add README.TXT #added change to README

$ git status 
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
# 
#   modified:   README.TXT
#

$ echo "good bye" >> README.TXT            #change README after adding
$ git status #now 'hello' is added to be committed but not 'good bye'
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   README.TXT
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   README.TXT
#

$ git commit -m "only hello" README.TXT        #commit, i would expect just 'hello' gets commited
[master 86e65eb] only hello
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)

$ git status         #QUESTION: How come there's nothing to commit?!
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

So the question is: Shouldn't `git commit` just commit the changes that were added with `git add`? And if so, why does it commit the second change even if i didn't add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git commit` will commit what is currently in the index and therefore what you explicitly added.

However, in your example, you are doing `git commit README.TXT` which will commit the files you specify, that is the current file `README.TXT`. Just do `git commit -m "only hello"` to commit the index.

Comment: hit it in the nail! The devil is really in the details :D Thank you!